# Настройка переадресации htaccess mod-rewrite rewriterule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Привет. 
Как настроить в файле .htaccess переадресацию такого вида:
http://www.site.com/?param=1 (http://www.site.com?param=1) если есть ?param=\d+ при этом обращение идет к корню сайта (не к внутренним разделам), должно перенаправить http://www.site.com/section?param=1 (http://www.site.com/section/?param=1)

Спаибо.

Comment: `http://www.site.com?param=1` <- такого быть не может.

Comment: Почему такого быть не может?

Comment: Да, путь может быть нулевой длины (спецификация глаголет), но браузеры сами дописывают слеш после хоста.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /section/?param=%1 [R=301,L]
```